# Cannot conda install riptable

Tags: python, python-riptable

```
conda install riptable
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (dlopen(/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libarchive.13.dylib
  Referenced from: <8447D0F3-4502-3ED6-8455-D7C22F99CAF6> /Users/John/anaconda3/lib/libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/John/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/John/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/John/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libarchive.13.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache))
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
 
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
 
  - riptable
 
Current channels:
 
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
 
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to
 
    https://anaconda.org
 
and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I'm trying to install riptable and I'm confused why it's not available on conda when in your documentation it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.